# add new headers parsing in tcpdump

Tags: networking, embedded, tcpdump

I have a necessity to add support for a proprietary headers that FPGA in our design inserts in incoming Ethernet frames between MAC header and payload. Obviously have to dig in tcpdump sources and libpcap, but could anybody give some hints at where exactly to start, so that I could save time?

Comment: You could also capture to a file (or stdout) and post-process.  But if attempting the question as asked, finding an existing patch that adds support for something else might be a quick way to identify what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to get a `DLT_`/`LINKTYPE_` value for your proprietary headers.  See [the link-layer header types page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) on the tcpdump.org Web site for the existing DLT_/LINKTYPE_ link-layer header type values and information on how to either use one of the `DLT_USER`*n* values internally or get a new value assigned if you plan to have people outside your organization use this.

Once you have the value assigned, you'll have to do some work on libpcap:

If you've been assigned a `DLT_` value, you'll have to modify the `pcap/pcap.h` file to add that link-layer type (and change the `DLT_MATCHING_MAX` value in that header file, and `LINKTYPE_MATCHING_MAX` in `pcap-common.c`, so that they are >= your `DLT_` value), or wait for whoever at tcpdump.org (which will probably be me) assigns your `DLT_` value and updates the libpcap Git repository (at which point you could use top-of-trunk libpcap).

If you plan to do live capturing, you may have to add a module to libpcap to support live capturing on your hardware, or, if your device looks like a regular networking device to your OS, so that you can use its native capture mechanism, modify the module for that OS to map whatever link-layer header type value the OS uses (e.g., a `DLT_` value on *BSD/OS X or an `ARPHRD_` value on Linux) to whatever `DLT_` you're using for your link-layer header type.

You'd have to modify `gencode.c` to be able to compile capture filters for your `DLT_` value.

Once that's done, libpcap should now work.

Now, for tcpdump:

Add an `if_print` routine that processes the proprietary headers (whether it just skips them or prints things for them), calls `ether_print()`, and then returns the sum of the length of your proprietary headers and the Ethernet header (`ETHER_HDRLEN` as defined in `ether.h`).  See `ether_if_print()` in `print-ether.c` for an example.

Add a declaration of that routine to `interface.h` and `netdissect.h`, and add an entry for it, with the routine name and `DLT_`, to `ndo_printers[]` if you copied `ether_if_print()` (which you should) or to `printers[]` if you didn't (if you didn't, you'll have to pass `&gndo` as the first argument to `ether_print()`).  Those arrays are in `tcpdump.c`.

Comment: thanks a lot for comprehensive answer. However I should've pointed out that the proprietary header is _inserted_ between a legitimate Ethernet header (e.g. with EthType 0x0800) and IP header. The proprietary header has a well defined signature bytes, so it'd be easy to distinguish from IPv4/IPv6 payload. Given this, could you give a hint at what code to look at. I think all I need is peek at first payload bytes right after the MAC header has been parsed.

Comment: Ow.  If you use `DLT_EN10MB`/`LINKTYPE_ETHERNET` for the capture, you'd have to hack tcpdump's `print-ether.c` to look for those special headers if the Ethertype is 0x0800 - or 0x86DD for IPv6 - and skip or process those headers before calling `ip_print()` or `ip6_print()`.  If you want to use filters, you'd also have to hack `gencode.c` in libpcap to generate code that skips over the proprietary header - that's a ***BIG*** task.